# How to use Candy (js based jabber client) with google app engine ?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, xmpp

is it possible to use Candy jabber client with app engine ?

http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/

Answer (score 0):

If it supports xmpp, then yes.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp

```
inbound_services:
- xmpp_message
- xmpp_presence
```